# ¿Cómo ejecutar plugin/librería al cambiar de vídeo?

Tags: jquery, html5, css3, videojs

Al ejecutar el código el **plugin** `videoJS` reemplaza el reproductor de vídeo de `HTML5`, ya la verdad muy contenta, me decía entre mi lo logre.

Pero al dar clic en el siguiente vídeo incluso volviendo al primer vídeo el **plugin** se pierde, dejándome el reproductor por defecto de `HTML5`

Lo pueden comprobar en [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhostingfree/maj0g36k/2/) o aquí:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function insertar_contenido(vid, elemento) {

    var contenido, fuente
    var url = elemento.attr("href")
    var ext = "mp4"
    var formato = ext
    var es_video = new RegExp("^.+\\." + ext + "$").test(url)
    var cargando = $('.loading')

    function mostrar() {
      cargando.fadeIn(200)
    }

    function ocultar() {
      cargando.fadeOut(100)
    }
    mostrar()
    var cuadro = vid.find(".cuadro")
    if (cuadro.length != 0) {
      $("#ocultado").append(cuadro)
    }
    if (es_video) {
     var json = {"aspectRatio":"640:267", "playbackRates": [1, 1.5, 2]};
     contenido = $(document.createElement("video"))
     fuente = $(document.createElement("source"))
     fuente.attr("src", url)
     fuente.attr("type", "video/" + formato)
     contenido.attr("controls", true)
     contenido.attr("autoplay", true)
     contenido.attr("class","video-js")
     contenido.attr('data-setup', JSON.stringify(json));
     contenido.on('waiting', mostrar)
     contenido.on('canplay', ocultar)
     contenido.append(fuente)
    } else {
      var id = elemento.attr("id")
      if (id == undefined) {
        contenido = $(document.createElement("iframe"))
        contenido.attr("src", url)
        contenido.on('load', ocultar)
      } else {
        contenido = $(document.createElement("div"))
        contenido.append($("#c_" + id))
        ocultar()
      }
    }
    vid.html("")
    vid.append(contenido)
    $("#enlaces a").removeClass("playing")
    elemento.addClass("playing")
  }

  var indice = 0
  var vid = $('#myvid')
  var primer_elemento = $("#enlaces a:first")
  var enlaces = $("#enlaces a").map((x, y) => {
    return {
      a: x,
      b: y
    }
  })

  insertar_contenido(vid, primer_elemento)
  primer_elemento.addClass("playing")

  $("#enlaces a.link").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var esto = $(this)

    indice = enlaces.filter((x, y) => y.b == this)[0].a

    insertar_contenido(vid, esto)
  })
  $("#atras").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var esto = $(this)
      --indice
    if (indice < 0) {
      indice += enlaces.length
    }
    enlaces[indice].b.click()
  })
  $("#siguiente").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var esto = $(this)
      ++indice
    if (indice >= enlaces.length) {
      indice -= enlaces.length
    }
    enlaces[indice].b.click()
  })
})
```

```css
#myvid {
  color: #ffff;
}

.container * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container *::after,
.container *::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2.title {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2em;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #A97A7A;
}

.container {
  width: 960px;
  background: #010101;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 550px;
}

.vidcontainer {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.videolist {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: rgb(76, 76, 76);
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.vids {
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #292626;
  max-height: 450px;
  border: 1px solid #616060;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  list-style: none;
  direction: rtl;
}

.vids::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
  background-color: #8A8A8A;
  border: 1px solid #AFACAC;
}

.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #FF8D00;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.vids a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #616060;
  padding: 8px 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}


/* --- controllers --- */

.controllers {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.controllers button {
  border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #777;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #4C4C4C;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.controllers button:focus {
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 7px #4C4C4C;
  border-color: #ff8d00;
  color: #ff8d00;
  background-color: #4C4C4C;
}

.btnPlay::after {
  content: "\f04b";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

.paused::after {
  content: "\f04c";
}

.sound::after {
  content: "\f027";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

.sound2:after {
  content: "\f028";
}

.muted::after {
  content: "\f026";
}

.btnFS::after {
  content: "\f065";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

.ads {
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #777;
  top: 27.5px;
  right: 40px;
  z-index: 11;
}

.bigplay {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 127.5px;
  left: 85px;
  z-index: 11;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #ff8d00;
}

.closeme {
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  border: 1px solid #ff8d00;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px!important;
  color: #ff8d00;
  font-size: 25px!important;
}

.playing {
  background-color: #999;
  border: 1px solid #ff8d00!important;
  -webkit-transition: 0s;
  -o-transition: 0s;
  transition: 0s;
}

.playing:after {
  content: "\f01d";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #ff8d00;
  float: left;
}


/* PROGRESS BAR CSS */

.topControl {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Progress bar */

.progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #999;
}

.progress span {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
}

.timeBar {
  z-index: 10;
  width: 0;
  background: #ff8d00;
}

.bufferBar {
  z-index: 5;
  width: 0;
  background: #eee;
}


/* time and duration */

.time {
  width: 12%;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 12px;
  right: -12%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.topControl:hover .time {
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.topControl:hover .progress {
  width: 88%;
  height: 12px;
}


/* VOLUME BAR CSS
        volume bar */

.volume {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 70px;
  height: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  background-color: #999;
}

.volumeBar {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ff8d00;
  z-index: 10;
}

.loading {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 141, 0, 0.5);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

i.fa.fa-spinner.fa-spin {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #000;
  top: 172.5px;
  left: 330px;
  position: absolute;
}

.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: #C2C2C2!important;
}

ul.speedcnt {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 60px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-transition: 0s;
  -o-transition: 0s;
  transition: 0s;
}

ul.speedcnt li {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'verdana', tahoma, serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

ul.speedcnt li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

ul.speedcnt li.selected {
  background-color: rgba(255, 141, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5-unsafe/video-js.css">-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5-unsafe/video.js"></script>-->

<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- If you'd like to support IE8 (for Video.js versions prior to v7) -->
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="vidcontainer">
    <div id="myvid"></div>
    <div class="loading">
      <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="videolist">
    <nav class="vids">
      <a id="atras" href="#">Atras</a>
      <a id="siguiente" href="#">Siguiente</a>
    </nav>
    <nav id="enlaces" class="vids">
      <a class="link" href="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4">test1</a>
      <a clases="link" href="https://www.wikipedia.org">test web</a>
      <a class="link" href="http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4">test2</a>
      <a class="link" href="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/H264/Other_Media/H264_test8_voiceclip_mp4_480x320.mp4">test3</a>
      <a class="link" href="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/MP4/ConvertedFiles/Media-Convert/Unsupported/dw11222.mp4">test4</a>
      <a class="link" href="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/MP4/ConvertedFiles/Media-Convert/Unsupported/test7.mp4">test5</a>
    </nav>
    <div id="ocultado" style="display: none">
      <div class="cuadro" id="c_link_10">Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src='https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video.js'></script>
```

Pensé que el **plugin** `videoJS` no funcionaba para varios vídeos en la misma pagina, pero realmente si funciona para varios vídeos aquí la prueba: https://jsfiddle.net/bq81phfy/

Entonces lo que se me ocurre que una posible solución es ejecutar al mismo tiempo el **plugin** `videoJS` al cambiar al siguiente vídeo o retroceder al vídeo anterior.

Mi problema: ¿Cómo logro que se ejecute la librerías del **plugin**? O ¿Cómo hacer que funcione el **plugin** para todos los vídeos?

Comment: ¿[Revisaste la documentación de `videojs`](https://videojs.com/getting-started/)? Una de las cosas que veo es que no agregas esa librería en tu código.

Comment: @A.Cedano Amigo he logrado que funcione, pero existe un problema, el **plugin** `videoJS` se pierde al cambiar de vídeo, es decir al continuar con el siguiente vídeo e incluso al retroceder al vídeo anterior. Tengo una idea de como se solucionaría pero no sé como realizarlo :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Te explico el problema

**Explicación corta:**

> La librería VideoJS no sabe que has agregado un nuevo elemento y no le aplica el cambio

**Explicación larga:**

> La librería de VideoJS cambia el reproductor automáticamente cuando encuentra la clase `video-js`, eso lo hace en el evento document ready, tu también agregas un evento al de document ready(con `$(document).ready()`), que va a inyectar el primer `video-js`, y este se ejecuta antes que el de VideoJS por lo que cuando la librería VideoJS busca los elementos que tengan la clase `video-js`, esta encuentra tu video y le da formato que quieres, y hasta ahí funciona todo bien. El detalle viene en el siguiente punto, al darle clic en el enlace, tu agregas otro elemento `video-js` pero nadie le dice a la librería que lo cargue (ella solo se ejecuta al principio) es por eso que aunque vuelvas al enlace anterior no funciona, por que remplazaste el elemento que la librería conocía por uno nuevo que la librería no conoce.

**Solución:**

Sencilla, decirle a la librería que hay un nuevo elemento video-js.

```
 videojs(contenido[0]);
```

Puedes verlo en acción: https://jsfiddle.net/3kg5yrtx/2/

Answer (score 3):

Yo habia hecho algo parecido pero la lista de video estaba dentro del script y no dentro de html.

Lo que me quedo pendiente es agregar en los botones el titulo del proximo video y del anterior, pero como al cliente no le interesaba, quedo asi, con los video de la empresa, ya que se reproducen automaticamente.

Espero sirva.

```js
var videoList = [
  {
    sources: [
      {
        src: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RVSgcA8ocM",
        type: "video/youtube"
      }
    ],
    poster: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6RVSgcA8ocM/hqdefault.jpg",
    title : "O'Sullivan v Wilson Final F10 2018 Champion of Champions"
  },
  {
    sources: [
      {
        src: "http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4",
        type: "video/mp4"
      }
    ],
    poster: "https://www.rt.com/static/img/og-logo-rt.png"
  },
  {
    sources: [
      {
        src: "http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/trailer.mp4",
        type: "video/mp4"
      }
    ],
    poster: "http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/poster.png"
  },
  {
    sources: [
      {
        src: "https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4",
        type: "video/mp4"
      }
    ],
    poster: "https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.png"
  },
  {
    sources: [
      {
        src: "http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/movie.mp4",
        type: "video/mp4"
      }
    ],
    poster: "http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/poster.png"
  },
  {
    sources: [
      {
        src: "//cdn.trancearoundtheworld.co.uk/files/tatw-301.6.mp3",
        type: "audio/mp3"
      }
    ],
    poster: "http://www.john00fleming.co.uk/mixes/podcasts/Nov08/GTG-Logo-Grunge_144.jpg"
  },
  {
    sources: [
      {
        src: "http://podcast.armadamusic.com/asot/episodes/episode490.m4a",
        type: "audio/mpeg"
      }
    ],
    poster: "http://podcast.armadamusic.com/asot/episodes/episode490.jpg"
  }
];

var player = videojs(document.querySelector("video"), {
  //inactivityTimeout: 0 // HIDE OR NOTE CONTROL BAR
});
try {
  player.volume(1);
} catch (e) {}

player.playlist(videoList);

document.querySelector(".previous").addEventListener("click", function() {
  player.playlist.previous();
});
document.querySelector(".next").addEventListener("click", function() {
  player.playlist.next();
});
document.querySelector(".jump").addEventListener("click", function() {
  player.playlist.currentItem(2);
  player.play();
});

player.playlist.autoadvance(0);

Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll("[name=autoadvance]"),
  function(el) {
    el.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var value = document.querySelector("[name=autoadvance]:checked").value;
      //alert(value);
      player.playlist.autoadvance(JSON.parse(value));
    });
  }
);


var Button = videojs.getComponent("Button");


var PrevButton = videojs.extend(Button, {

  constructor: function() {
    Button.apply(this, arguments);

    this.addClass("vjs-icon-previous-item");
    this.controlText("Previous");
    
  },

  handleClick: function() {
    console.log("click");
    player.playlist.previous();
  }
});

var NextButton = videojs.extend(Button, {

  constructor: function() {
    Button.apply(this, arguments);

    this.addClass("vjs-icon-next-item");
    this.controlText("Next");
  },

  handleClick: function() {
    console.log("click");
    player.playlist.next();
  }
});

videojs.registerComponent("NextButton", NextButton);
videojs.registerComponent("PrevButton", PrevButton);

player.getChild("controlBar").addChild("PrevButton", {}, 0);
player.getChild("controlBar").addChild("NextButton", {}, 2);
```

```html
<link href="http://videojs.github.io/font/css/videojs-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.16/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.16/video.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/videojs/videojs-youtube/master/src/Youtube.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/atlance01/vrapp-ionic/master/www/js/lib/videojs-playlist.js"></script>

<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls width="640px" height="360px" data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["html5", "youtube"] }'></video>
<br><br>
<button class="previous">Atras</button>
<button class="next">Siguiente</button>
<button class="jump">Reproducir otra vez</button>
```

Comment: Hola amigo, se ve genial :) para solo uso de vídeos, pero en mi código es de multi uso, acabo de editar la pregunta en ese mismo código yo puedo acceder a 3 cosas a `videos` a `sitio web` y a `solo texto`por ejemplo si haces clic en el `test1` el código inserta el vídeo en su respectiva etiqueta que es `<video></video>` si das clic en el `test web` el código inserta el sitio web en un `<iFrame></iFrame>` y sus botones de siguiente o atrás funciona para todo el listado que va ejecutando de manera correcta los archivos a sus respectivas etiquetas.

Comment: La generación de la etiqueta video con sus respectiva rutas lo hace la siguiente línea de código `jQuery` `if (es_video) {}` no será posible crear una funcionalidad similar dentro de esa línea de código para que funcione el **plugin** para todos los videos y no solamente de uno como lastimosamente está sucediendo en mi código :(

Comment: Entiendo, entonces lo que puedes hacer es un html para cada video que contenga los videos, el sitio y texto.

Comment: Todo de manera separada, no me ayudaría porque ya el código jQuery cumple esa función de mostrar todo en un mismo contenedor, y, no mostrar dato en diferentes partes, sobre todo porque realmente he causado un gran dolor de cabeza con este código y también problemas al generar los enlaces con PHP, porque todo esos enlaces vienen desde la base de datos. Agradezco la intención de ayudarme, pero a lo mejor solo falta algún detalle en mi código para que funcione el **plugin** en todos los videos y no solo en el primero. Saludos.

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices, te dejo este [link](http://www.mainsailvideo.com/videojs-playLists-master/example/spots.html) y bueno mil disculpas por no poder ayudarte a resolverlo.